# Need help dereferencing this uchar* to print its contents

Tags: c++, opencv

Here is the code I'm running for reference about what I'm about to ask at bottom of code:

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui_c.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

uchar* cv_Mat_ptr_index(Mat* self, int i) {
    return self->ptr(i);
}

Mat* cv_create_Mat_typed(int rows, int cols, int type) {
    return new Mat(rows, cols, type);
}

int main(  )
{ uchar a;

float data[4][2] = { {501, 10}, {255, 10}, {501, 255}, {10, 501} };
Mat* mat = cv_create_Mat_typed(4, 2, CV_64F);
 for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
   for(int j = 0; j < 2; j++){
     cv_Mat_ptr_index(mat, i)[j] = data[i][j];

     printf("%i\n",  cv_Mat_ptr_index(mat, i)[j]);}}
}
```

Directly above this in the for loop is the wrapper function I use to add the contents of "data" into the matrix "mat" . It is called cv_Mat_ptr_index. At this line `cv_Mat_ptr_index(mat, i)[j] = data[i][j];`  it sets all of the data in "data" into "mat".  I'm trying to get this line `printf("%i\n",  cv_Mat_ptr_index(mat, i)[j])` to print the contents of data as a 4x2 matrix i.e. this exactly:

501 10 
 255 10 
 501 255 
 10 501

but the best I could get was below.  I tried changing the location of the for loops end brackets. tried calling with a %i, %s,%u because the numbers were wrong...I changed the 2nd cv_Mat_ptr_index`` ` line by taking off the ``[j]` which changed that line to uchar* output so I could use a  u%. Tried using cout.

..I could go on and on, but I could use a little help getting the `printf("%i\n",  cv_Mat_ptr_index(mat, i)[j]` line to print the matrix as above..I'm using this in a project and I can't change the top 2 C wrappers in any way.  I'm trying to stop using mat::at as much, so learning how to print a matrix with this function would really help.

`245
 10
 255
 10
 245
 255
 10
 245`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I print a Mat element using this basic C wrapper for the C++ Mat Class ptr object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22469666/how-do-i-print-a-mat-element-using-this-basic-c-wrapper-for-the-c-mat-class-pt)

Comment: Somewhere in that code you're converting every element of the array to an unsigned char.  An unsigned char can only represent numbers between 0 and 255. When you assign 501 to an unsigned char, the resulting number is 245.

Comment: @user3386109 Thanks for joining in, can you help me get it to do what I want it to..Even if I found the uchar its still printing just 5 numbers...cv_Mat_ptr_index is a uchar* return.

Comment: It was too much for a comment, so I posted an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Also, use the correct format specifier:

```
  printf("%hhu\n", cv_Mat_ptr_index(mat, i)[j]) ;
```

Comment: I appreciate your response...I noticed your code has an extra parentheses in it `printf("%hhu\n", *( cv_Mat_ptr_index(mat, i)[j]) ) );<-` and when I run it in place of the lower `cv_Mat_ptr_index` in the code above. I get a "invalid type argument of unary" error....do you know why it's doing that?

Comment: I didn't notice it was already dereferenced enough, my bad. Anyways, hhu is the right format specifier for unsigned char. %i expects int, which is wider, so printf can't work with that.

Comment: Oh wait a sec, now I see in your original code you are trying to print float, but convert it to uchar before doing that. As @user3411335 noticed, it won't work like this. Let me google this library. It is called OpenCV, right?

Comment: Is this the `ptr` you use here?
http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html?highlight=ptr#mat-ptr

Comment: Isn't there another cv_Mat_ptr_index wrapper function somewhere? Maybe something like cv_Mat_ptr_index_typed, where you can supply the argument CV_64F as you did it with create?

Comment: your `data` stores floats, so try to cast to `*float` , I wrote a new answer about that.

Answer (score 0):

As I see it, the problem is with this line

```
cv_Mat_ptr_index(mat, i)[j] = data[i][j];
```

Since `cv_Mat_ptr_index(mat, i)` returns a `uchar *` that's equivalent to

```
uchar *mptr = cv_Mat_ptr_index(mat, i);
mptr[j] = data[i][j];
```

In the process, `data[i][j]` is converted to a `uchar`, which means the data can only be in the range 0 to 255.  Note that all the numbers that are in that range work correctly.  The only number outside that range is 501, which is converted to 245.

I'm not familiar with the `cv_Mat` family of functions, but I see that the `cv_create_Mat_typed` function takes a type as its third argument.  There must be a corresponding function that returns that same type, so your mission is to find that function.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with it being uchar in the first place, so yeah, correct format will not help.
Anyways, if there is cv_create_Mat_typed  to use CV_64F , maybe there is a related

```
 cv_Mat_ptr_index_cv_64f(Mat *self, int i)
```

if you don't find that I think, as a last resort you can try casting it to *float

```
 ((float*) cv_Mat_ptr_index(mat, i)[j] ) = data[i][j];
 printf("%f\n",  ( (float*)cv_Mat_ptr_index(mat, i)[j] ) );
```

I didn't try to run or compile this, so it can have typos. The point is, the original Mat object likely allocated space enough for the type. So hopefully, you get lucky.